# Enhancing a scanned document with Gimp

Tags: gimp, scanning, image-editing

I have a pretty good scan of a document, in JPG format[1] that has Fuchsia  type printed text, and black handwritten text. I wish to remove the handwritten text, and sharpen and colour enhance the Fuchsia text slightly. I am a Gimp, and image editing noob in general, so my guesses are as follows:

1. Remove the black handwriting with a soft brush the same colour as the surrounding blank, whitish paper. This I can sort of do.
   2.Then blur the new white with the rest of the white. I have no clue.
   3.Then straighten some borders. I suspect there are ways of doing this automagically, but I can draw lines if need be.
2. Then select all the Fuchsia  colour with the magic wand thing and invoke some sort of 'enhance' command'.

What have I got wrong and what have I missed?

[1] Is that a good format for editing? I know it isn't for presentation. Or is good ol' BMP best for manipulation?

Answer (score 2):

Gimp has a "Select by color" option that you can use to only highlight certain areas. Shift + O will invoke this option. I would avoid hand-corrections if possible, unless you have a very steady hand.

You best bet might be to select all fushia areas, and copy and paste them onto a different layer. Then you can edit the original layer without danger of damagin the information you truly want. When you done, just merge the layers back together, and save in whatever format(I prefer PNG).

Comment: The fuschia colours aren't all uniform, so I would have to select everything that isn't white, or that is white, and move that. How can I make all the white uniform?

Comment: yoou can adjust the sensitivity of the color selection(the threshold) to make it more accepting of similar colors, not just the exact color you selected. Typically, I try to edit the features that I want rather than try to remove the things I don't. Making the white uniform is similar to adjusting the threshold on the paint bucket so it it more "accepting" of painting dis simialr colors. You'll need to just play with it to find the values you need, every situation is unique when it comes to this type of thing.